# Create frequency matrix using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['01', 'A'],
    ['01', 'B'],
    ['01', 'C'],
    ['02', 'A'],
    ['02', 'B'],
    ['03', 'B'],
    ['03', 'C']
], columns=['id', 'category'])
```

How do I create a frequency matrix like this?

```
    A   B   C           
A   2   2   1
B   2   3   2
C   1   2   2
```

One way to do it is through self join:

```
result = df.merge(df, on='id')
pd.pivot_table(
    result,
    index='category_x',
    columns='category_y',
    values='id',
    aggfunc='count'
)
```

But this will make the data size very large, is there any efficient way to do it without using self join?

**Edit**
My original post was closed for duplication of `pivot_table`. But `pivot_table` only accept different `columns` and `index`. In my case, I have only one `category` column. So

```
# Does not work
pivot_table(df, column='category', index='category', ...)
```

does not work.

Comment: The duplicate does not only mention pivot_table. The accepted answer alone mentions at least 7 different ways of doing this.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  Those 7 different ways are just alternative way to make a r * c pivot table. They only work if you have different `row` and `column`. But I have the same row and column. My expected output is more like a correlation matrix, but replace with frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from Python standard library:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement


pair_counts = Counter(
    df.groupby("id")
    .agg(list)
    .apply(lambda x: list(combinations_with_replacement(x["category"], 2)), axis=1)
    .sum()
)

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for pair, count in pair_counts.items():
    new_df.at[pair[0], pair[1]] = count
    new_df.at[pair[1], pair[0]] = count

new_df = new_df.astype(int)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output

   A  B  C
A  2  2  1
B  2  3  2
C  1  2  2
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. But `pair_counts` still list out all the possibility. Is there more pandasic way to do it?

Comment: Hi, not that I know of, sorry. But doesn't that avoid making the data size very large, though (it is only counting), which seemed to be your main concern? Cheers.